# Select All Checkbox / Twitter Bootstrap Rails

Tags: html, checkbox, html-table, twitter-bootstrap-rails, selectall

I'd like to know how to create a "Select All" checkbox in my table. 
The only thing is that I'm not using input tag for the checkboxes, I'm using f.check_box.
Here's my tbody:

```
<td>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <%= f.check_box :members, :name => 'point[members]['+member.id+']' %>
  </label>
</td>
```